# Why is this a contravariant functor?

Tags: category-theory

> Find a universal element of the contravariant power set functor $P : \text{Set}^{\text{op}} \rightarrow \text{Set}$

By definition of universal element for a functor $H: D \rightarrow \text{Set}$: it's a pair $\langle r, e \in Hr \rangle$ such that for every $\langle d, x \in Hd \rangle$ there's a unique $f : r \rightarrow d$ in $D$ such that $(Hf)e=x$.

Since I'm looking for a universal element, I'm looking for a set and it's subset pair $\langle X,A\rangle$ such that for all $\langle Y,B \rangle$ there's a unique $f : X \rightarrow Y$ in $\text{Sets}^{\text{op}}$ such that $(Pf) A = B$.

But if $f : X \rightarrow Y$, then $Pf : PY \rightarrow PX$ since it's a contravariant functor.

So how can $(Pf)A=B$ possibly be satisfied since $A \notin PY$?

Comment: For $A\in X$, $Pf(A)=\{f(x):\ x\in A\}\in PY$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Careful: if $f : X \to Y$ in $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$ then $f$ is a function from $Y$ to $X$ and thus $\mathcal{P}f$ is a function from $\mathcal{P}(X)$ to $\mathcal{P}(Y)$. Now, if $f$ is a function from $Y$ to $X$ and $A \subseteq X$, then
$$\mathcal{P}f(A) = f^{-1}[A] = \{ y \in Y \mid f(y) \in A \} \subseteq Y$$
so everything makes sense just fine!